# How to calculate what will be the position of a widget in a QGridLayout?

Tags: c++, qt

I write this code to create a 'transition' animation, to when new items are added or hidden in the layout
and also when the number of items per column has changed:

[image: gif.gif]

As seen on the right, by default the layout just abrupt adjust the frame position
while on the left it smoothly (the gif lost a lot of the animation quality) move the frame to the adjusted position.

To achieve this i have created a `dummy` QScrollArea in which i needed to replicate everything from the
"original" QScrollArea just to calculate what would be the destination position of the frame.

I have blow my mind trying to understand how does the layout calculate these positions, appreciate any help
in how to calculate this, then i wouldnt need a dummy QScrollArea.

`main.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    w.dummyWidget->move(w.x() + w.width() + 200, w.y());
    w.dummyWidget->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

`mainwindow.h`

```
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindowClass; };
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    
    bool eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event);
    void setAnimation(int framePerColumn = 0);
    void setframeCount(int value);
    void setframePerColumn(int value);

    QWidget* dummyWidget = nullptr;
    QScrollArea* dummyScrollArea = nullptr;
    QGridLayout* dummyScrollAreaLayout = nullptr;

    QScrollArea* scrollArea = nullptr;
    QGridLayout* scrollAreaLayout = nullptr;
private:
    Ui::MainWindowClass *ui;
};
```

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"


// This eventFilter is just to resize the dummyScrollArea
// to the same size of the scrollArea.
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::Resize)
    {
        QResizeEvent *resizeEvent = dynamic_cast<QResizeEvent*>(event);
        dummyScrollArea->setFixedSize(resizeEvent->size());
        dummyScrollArea->topLevelWidget()->resize(resizeEvent->size());
    }

    return false; // false: allow other event filters to process the event.
}



void MainWindow::setAnimation(int framePerColumn)
{
    // Necessary to disable the layout while the 
    // animation is running.
    scrollAreaLayout->setEnabled(false);

    QParallelAnimationGroup* animationGroup = new QParallelAnimationGroup();
    QVariantAnimation* frame_ani = nullptr;
    QEasingCurve::Type curve = QEasingCurve::Type::Linear;
    int duration = 400;
    int i = 0;

    QVector<QWidget*> frameList;

    for (int row = 0; row < dummyScrollAreaLayout->rowCount(); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < dummyScrollAreaLayout->columnCount(); col++)
        {
            QLayoutItem* dummyItem = dummyScrollAreaLayout->itemAtPosition(row, col);
            if (dummyItem)
            {
                QLayoutItem* item = scrollAreaLayout->itemAt(i);
                if (item)
                {
                    frameList << item->widget();
                    frame_ani = new QPropertyAnimation(item->widget(), "pos");
                    frame_ani->setEasingCurve(curve);
                    frame_ani->setDuration(duration);
                    frame_ani->setStartValue(item->widget()->pos());
                    frame_ani->setEndValue(dummyItem->widget()->pos());
                    animationGroup->addAnimation(frame_ani);
                }
        i++;
        }
        }
    }



    animationGroup->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);

    connect(animationGroup, &QAbstractAnimation::finished, this, [=] 
    {
    // Readjust the widgets into the rows/ columns.
        if (framePerColumn)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < frameList.size(); i++)
                scrollAreaLayout->addWidget(frameList[i], i / framePerColumn, i % framePerColumn);
        }

        // Reactivate the layout.
        scrollAreaLayout->setEnabled(true);
        scrollAreaLayout->activate();
    });
}



void MainWindow::setframeCount(int value)
{
    QList<QWidget*> dummyFrameList = 
        dummyScrollArea->viewport()->findChildren<QWidget*>(Qt::FindDirectChildrenOnly);

    int frameCount = dummyFrameList.size();
    int framePerColumn = findChild<QSpinBox*>("framePerColumn")->value();



    // Create new frames.
    if (value > frameCount)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
        {
            if (i < frameCount)
                dummyFrameList[i]->show();
            else
            {
                QFrame* frame = new QFrame(dummyScrollArea->viewport());
                frame->setStyleSheet("QFrame { background-color: rgba(70, 70, 70, 70); border: 0px; }");
                frame->setFixedSize(100, 100);
                frame->show();

                QLabel* label = new QLabel(QString::number(i), frame);
                label->setStyleSheet("font: 24px; font-weight: 900; color: red;");
                label->show();

                dummyScrollAreaLayout->addWidget(frame, i / framePerColumn, i % framePerColumn);
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++)
        {
            if (i < value)
                dummyFrameList[i]->show();
            else
                dummyFrameList[i]->hide();
        }
    }



    // Necessary to force the dummyScrollAreaLayout
    // to update the position of the widgets.
    dummyScrollAreaLayout->activate();



    QList<QWidget*> frameList = 
        scrollArea->viewport()->findChildren<QWidget*>(Qt::FindDirectChildrenOnly);
    frameCount = frameList.size();

    // Create new frames.
    if (value > frameCount)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
        {
            if (i < frameCount)
                frameList[i]->show();
            else
            {
                QFrame* frame = new QFrame(scrollArea->viewport());
                frame->setStyleSheet("QFrame { background-color: rgba(70, 70, 70, 70); border: 0px; }");
                frame->setGeometry(dummyScrollAreaLayout->itemAt(i)->widget()->geometry());
                frame->setFixedSize(100, 100);
                frame->show();

                QLabel* label = new QLabel(QString::number(i), frame);
                label->setStyleSheet("font: 24px; font-weight: 900; color: red;");
                label->show();

                frameList << frame;
                scrollAreaLayout->addWidget(frame, i / framePerColumn, i % framePerColumn);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++)
        {
            if (i < value)
                frameList[i]->show();
            else
                frameList[i]->hide();
        }
    }



    setAnimation();
}



void MainWindow::setframePerColumn(int framePerColumn)
{
    // Remove all frames and reappend according to
    // framePerColumn value.
    QVector<QLayoutItem*> itemList;
    while (dummyScrollAreaLayout->count())
        itemList << dummyScrollAreaLayout->takeAt(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++)
        dummyScrollAreaLayout->addItem(itemList[i], i / framePerColumn, i % framePerColumn);

    // Necessary to force the dummyScrollAreaLayout
    // update the position of the widgets.
    dummyScrollAreaLayout->activate();

    setAnimation(framePerColumn);
}



MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindowClass())
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QSpinBox* frameCount = new QSpinBox(this);
    frameCount->setObjectName("frameCount");
    frameCount->setMinimum(1);
    frameCount->setMaximum(100);
    frameCount->setValue(9);
    frameCount->setMaximumWidth(60);
    QLabel* label = new QLabel("Frame count", this);

    connect(frameCount, &QSpinBox::valueChanged, this, &MainWindow::setframeCount);



    QSpinBox* framePerColumn = new QSpinBox(this);
    framePerColumn->setObjectName("framePerColumn");
    framePerColumn->setMinimum(1);
    framePerColumn->setMaximum(100);
    framePerColumn->setValue(5);
    framePerColumn->setMaximumWidth(60);
    QLabel* label_2 = new QLabel("Frame per column", this);

    connect(framePerColumn, &QSpinBox::valueChanged, this, &MainWindow::setframePerColumn);



    scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);   
    QWidget* widget = new QWidget(scrollArea);
    scrollArea->installEventFilter(this);
    scrollArea->setViewport(widget);
    scrollArea->setStyleSheet("QScrollArea { background-color: rgba(70, 70, 70, 70); border: 0px; }");
    scrollAreaLayout = new QGridLayout(widget);



     QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout(ui->centralWidget);
     layout->addWidget(frameCount, 0, 0);
     layout->addWidget(label, 0, 1);
     layout->addWidget(framePerColumn, 0, 2);
     layout->addWidget(label_2, 0, 3);

     QSpacerItem* spacer = new QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
     layout->addItem(spacer, 0, 4);

     layout->addWidget(scrollArea, 1, 0, 2, 5);



     dummyWidget = new QWidget();
     dummyWidget->setWindowTitle("Dummy QScrollArea");
     dummyScrollArea = new QScrollArea(dummyWidget);   
     widget = new QWidget(dummyScrollArea);
     dummyScrollArea->setViewport(widget);
     dummyScrollArea->setStyleSheet("QScrollArea { background-color: rgba(70, 70, 70, 70); border: 0px; }");
     dummyScrollAreaLayout = new QGridLayout(widget);
   
}
```

To be more precise my question is how to calculate what will be the widgets positions after the layout has been modified.

For example, when there's 6 widget in the GridLayout, 3 per column:

```
|--| (0,0)       |--| (150,0)       |--| (250, 0)
|--| (0,150)     |--| (150,150)     |--| (250, 150)
```

and it will be changed to 2 widget per column:

```
|--| (?,?)       |--| (?,?)
|--| (?,?)       |--| (?,?)
|--| (?, ?)      |--| (?, ?)
```

How to `calculate` what will be the new position of each widgets in the layout? In my example code above I have created the `dummy` QScrollArea just to get these `(?,?)` positions because I didn't understand how to calculate it.

All widgets have a `fixed` size, the layout size constraint is `SetDefaultConstraint`.

Comment: You might want to create your own layout, or just use "manual layout" (override parent widget resize event etc, and call your own method to position children).

Comment: Im not looking for a custom layout, just how to calculate what will be the widgets positions based on the viewport size / widgets per column.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Your animation and the text with it is about how widgets teleport from one place (which appears to be correct) to another (which also appears to be correct). It does not looks like you have any trouble using the layout to place widgets in it, as your question title suggest. Could you please clarify?
My answer will be different depending on what you say.

Comment: I forgot to ask if there are any size constraints on the widgets, such as them all having the same fixed size? or only having a fixed size maybe? or ... what would it be?

Comment: Are you just asking, where QGridLayout sources are?  Because I don't think there is any other "formal" documentation on how the positions and sizes are calculated.

Comment: @Atmo i edited the question, let me know if its clear now.

Comment: As your widgets have a fixed size, I'd create a hidden widget to make the calculation in advance. `w` would be your main hidden widget with a grid layout to fill with empty subwidgets (each of the subwidgets have the same size as your real widgets). Once everything is laid down, call `QLayout::activate` to calculate the subwidgets' positions without showing `w` on screen. Finally, make sure to sync  the sizes of your helper widgets the same to your real widgets with signals/slots. Voila! you can extract their positions. Let me know if it looks OK as a solution + if you need a code sample.

Comment: But this is exactly what i did the code sample i provided, the unique diference is that the dummy widget which I'm extracting the positions isn't hidden.

Comment: Then what's wrong with the positions? The only difference I see between your left and right anirmations is that widgets teleport on the right instead of smoothly moving. If you're able to correctly position widgets for 2 rows and 3 columns, surely you can do the same with 3 rows and 2 columns. At the very least, when asked if the issue was the positions or the animations, you seem to have said it is the positions but again, I do not see what is wrong about it by reading your question.